# How to write smart contracts using solidity to control other smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

I am learning blockchain tech and try to write some smart contracts racking my brains for the following things using Proxy.

1. a smart contract that can extract data from a different contract and save it locally
2. allow this contract to have control over other contracts to delete data in case of false security access

Comment: What kind of data do you want to extract? Is it a simple variable, struct, mapping, or something else? Is this also the same kind of data you want to delete?

Answer (score 1):

contract "controlling" other smart contracts is not exactly a good term. but form what i understand you are trying to make a master contract that uses other contracts and has elevated access to their stored data.

the idea is simple if you are making all of these contracts. You can implement an **ownership** mechanism (openZepplin `Ownable` would be a good start) on each slave contract and after deployment, you can switch the ownership to the main contract.

In each slave contract, you can implement methods that read, modify and delete the data stored on each contract, these methods would be only accessible if the message sender (`msg.sender`) is the existing owner stored in the contract. this way you can seal the ownership of any contract to the main contract.